# Lift basic example sign up error w/ net.liftweb.record.{ MetaMegaProtoUser, MegaProtoUser }

Tags: scala, lift

I'm taking the Lift basic example project for 2.5-M3 and want to adapt
it for Record and Mongo.

It all works fine except when I try to sign up the generated form
only has one password field and no repeated field. When filling that
one field I get an error message "Passwords do not match".

Comment: It's impossible to tell what might have changed. You need to post the code from your snippet, as well as the corresponding html, so we can see what might be going on.

Comment: There is a discussion on the Lift mailing list about this. Seems to have a possible workaround: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/liftweb/w-c15dvdfow